# How to accept confirmation Automatically in PowerShell for Outlook

Tags: powershell, outlook

How to accept confirmation Automatically in PowerShell for Outlook
I have script for Export attachments from email from Outlook  - see next
It works correctly on one PC, but on another PC is there a problem:
Outlook gives message and wants answer:

```
              Permit          Denny            Help
```

If I manually click on Permit or Denny it works correctly.  I want to automate it.
Can you give me some suggestion how to do it in PowerShell?
I have tried to set  Outlook  to not give this message but I didn’t  success.
My script:

```
    # <-- Script --------->
    # script works with outlook Inbox folder
    # check if email have attachments with ".txt" and save those attachments to $filepath

    # path for exported files - attachments
    $filepath = "d:\Exported_files\" 
    # create object outlook
    $o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $n = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    # $f - folder „dorucena posta“ 6 - Inbox
    $f = $n.GetDefaultFolder(6)   # 6 - Inbox
    # select newest 10 emails, from it olny this one with attachments
    $f.Items| select -last 10| Where {$_.Attachments}| foreach {
    # process only unreaded mail
        if($_.unread -eq $True) {
    # processed mail set as read, not to process this mail again next day
            $_.unread = $False        
            $SenderName = $_.SenderName
    Write-Host "Email from: ", $SenderName

    # process all attachments
            $_.attachments|foreach {
                $a = $_.filename    
                If ($a.Contains(".txt")) {
                Write-Host $SenderName,"    ", $a
    # copy *.txt attachments to folder $filepath
                $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath "$a"))            
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Write-Host "Finish"
    # <------ End Script ---------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that security prompt is generate on line 
" $SenderName = $_.SenderName "
Realy I dont need to use SenderName and I deleted this line.
Now script works OK without any message.